# (x % mod) ** 2 = x**2 % mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I read such a algorithms to implement expmod computation in [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.6)

```
#+begin_src ipython :session sicp :results output
def expmod(base, exp, m):
    # base case
    if exp == 0: return 1
    if evenp(exp):
        return expmod(base, exp/2, m) ** 2 % m
    else:
        return base * expmod(base, exp-1, m) % m

def evenp(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

print(expmod(2, 8, 7))
 #+end_src

 #+RESULTS:
 : 4
```

The algorithms employed the principle that

```
 (x % mod) ** 2 = x**2 % mod
```

How could prove it?

Comment: ty, answered my question. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is wrong.

E.g.

$$(8\bmod 5)^2=9$$

but

$$(8^2)\bmod5=4.$$

Comment: One would presume that they meant they are congruent, in this case, 9%5 == 4%5.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: sorry but I am answering the question as stated *and as programmed*.

Comment: The code provided ends the even and odd return lines with `% m`, which as I said, means they are congruent.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: you are giving the OP misleading information. The code uses the modulo operator, which returns a value. There is no test for congruency.

Comment: appreciate it very much for the  kind help.  Got the idea of the code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You misunderstand my point. If every line ends with `% m`, which as you say, returns a value, then it's not possible to end up with values larger than `m`. As is in your answer, you get $9$, which would become $4$ *as programmed*.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: `(x % mod) ** 2 = x**2 % mod`

Comment: That is the stated *principal* which holds if you mod both sides, which the given program does in fact do.